# How to start Activity arbitrarily

Tags: android, android-activity

Every time when an `Activity` is created, I will keep its reference. After that, for some reason, I will want to show it, how can I do that? I don't want to change this `Activity` to `single task` or `single instance` mode, because I want to use it as `standard` mode.

Below I show some code to clarify the question.

I have this global variable (global across all the Activity) :

```
ArrayList<Activity> list = new ArrayList<Activity>();
```

In the `Activity onCreate`, I will execute the code as below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    list.add(this);
}
```

Now, if I want to show/start the second `Activity` in the `list`. How can I do that?

Comment: Don't store the reference of an Activity in a global list plsss..

Comment: @M-WaJeEh That is an example only, I am not storing it in global list indeed. [Eidted: sorry, typo]

Comment: Thats what I said, **don't** store the reference of an Activity in a **global** list.

Comment: @GMsoF : You really need to read about Application Fundamentals http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html and also about the Activity class http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html What you are proposing will potentially cause a serious memory leak scenario.

Comment: There is no way to bring a specific activity instance to the front (if you have multiple instances of that activity in your task stack). You need to rearchitect your application. You can't build Android apps like this. You also need to understand that Android can kill off your application at any time if it is in the background. That means that your list of activities will be gone. Please explain what it is you are trying to achieve and maybe we can suggest an alternative architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store `Activity`'s references in a `List`, instead store their class like this:

```
list.add(this.getClass());
```

And later just launch the `Activity` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, list.get(0));
intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Comment: With this method, I still couldn't start/show the activity that I want. Because there might be more than one `Activity's instance` that have the same class name. How?